# How can I close tabs related to the extension when browser closes

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to close tabs related to the extension, like tabs with url `chrome-extension://<extension-id>/index.html`, when a browser closes

In the background script, I tried to close tabs with `chrome.tabs.remove` function when `chrome.windows.onRemoved` event fired, but looks like it fires too late when tabs not available. Also, because Chrome doesn't open immediately, I tried to use `chrome.windows.onCreated` event, but turned out it only worked on my computer with Windows and didn't work on Mac.

Am I doing something wrong or maybe there is another way to close them, like adding a script on every page that will be executed when the browser closes?

Comment: There's no onBrowserExit event so there's no straightforward and reliable way to implement what you want. As you already know there are some hackish workarounds. An even more convoluted one would be to write an external utility that monitors the browser process then modifies "Current Session" file directly.

Comment: What about using chrome.runtime.onStartup event to get a list of your extension's tabs by querying chrome.tabs.query({url: chrome.runtime.getURL('*')}, tt => tt.length && chrome.tabs.remove(tt.map(t => t.id))) ?

Comment: @wOxxOm, no, chrome.runtime.onStartup not getting fired

Comment: Then it's a bug either in Chrome or in your extension. If it's the former you can report on https://crbug.com. BTW if your background script is persistent:true there's no need for onStartup - just perform the check at the start of the script.

Comment: @wOxxOm, tabs not available at this moment, chrome.tabs.query doesn't return anything

Comment: Well, what about registering a chrome.tabs.onCreated listener with a debouncer inside so it kicks in when the initial burst of creating the tabs completes?